# Help with multivariable limit involving log

Tags: multivariable-calculus

i have to find the limit when $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ of $$\frac{\log(1+x^2 + y^2)}{x^2+y^2+yx^3}$$ 
According to wolframalpha the limit equals 1 but i have spent hours trying to solve it and i can't figure out how to get to the solution. I tried to use the sqeeze theorem but i couldn't find two bound functions approaching to 1, if this is the way could you give me some instructions or tips on how to find the two functions in theese cases? I've also tried using polar coordinates but got nowhere. Thanks in advance.
Regards

Eliana

Comment: Hint: $\frac{\log(1+t)}{t}$ tends to $1$ as $t\to 0$. Now do something to your expression so you will be able to use this fact.

Comment: This is the usual limit which is solved using polar coordinates. Put $x= r \cos \theta$ and $y= r \sin \theta$, and the use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: I really preciate your help, i've been thinking about your advices but i am null, it seems that i'm missing some technique. @uniquesolution: if i write t=x^2 + y^2 then in the denominator there is that yx^3 term bothering and it can be positive, negative or anything, i don't know what to do whith it. Also i am not really familiarized with substituting two independent variables by just one, i don't completly understand how it works, i'll keep on thinking about it. Crostul: i've done polar subst but i still can't find the two bound function i need to use squeeze thrm. Thanks to both anyway

Comment: Ok, i've used the path y=x and got to the 0/0 undeterminate form again so i applied two times l'hopital and i finally got that limit goes to 1. But i still need to prove that's actually the limit of the two variables function, so i guess i have to work directly with the epsilon-delta definition. Any thoughts about how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$, then dividing the top and bottom of the fraction by $x^2+y^2$ we get:

$$\frac{\log(1+x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2+yx^3}=\frac{\frac{\log(1+x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}}{1+\frac{yx^3}{x^2+y^2}}$$

Now, if $|y|<1$ and $|x|<1$, then $|yx^3|<|x^3|<|x|(x^2+y^2)$, so if not both $x,y$ are zero then $\left|\frac{yx^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|<|x|$. Therefore, 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{yx^3}{x^2+y^2} = 0\hskip 1.5cm (1)$$
Also, substituting $x^2+y^2 = t$, we have 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\log(1+x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\log(1+t)}{t}=1\hskip 1.5cm (2)$$
From (1) and (2) we deduce that the limit in question is equal to $1$.

Comment: One million thanks,  your reasoning is very clear and it helps me a lot